# Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "List[Union[str, int]]")

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

If I run this code through mypy:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1: list[str] = []
    list2: list[str | int] = []
    list2 = list1
```

It gives me following error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "List[Union[str, int]]")
```

Why? Isn't a `list[str]` a subset of `list[str | int]`? If yes, then why can't I assign `list1` which doesn't have wider range of possible types to `list2`?

Comment: Because lists are mutable. You're thinking of the _read_ case but you can also _write_. `list1` is not a suitable value because if you then `list2.push(123)` you're adding an integer to a list of strings. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62814180/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic types can be classified as *covariant*, *contravariant*, or *invariant*. When `u` is a subtype of `v`, a generic type `g` is

1. *covariant* when `g[u]` is a subtype of `g[v]`,
2. *contravariant* when `g[v]` is a subtype of `g[u]`, or
3. *invariant* when neither `g[u]` nor `g[v]` is a subtype of the other.

`list` is invariant because lists are mutable, in which case it is not safe to substitute one concrete type of list for another. Immutable *sequences* are covariant: `Sequence[str]` is, indeed, a subtype of `Sequence[str | int]`, so you could do the following:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1: Sequence[str] = []
    list2: Sequence[str | int] = []
    list2 = list1
```

The only thing you can do with a `Sequence`, regardless of whether it is a list, tuple, etc, is *read* from it, and anything reading from `list2` will know it can't assume that any given element is a `str` or an `int` (though it will be one or the other, rather than, say, a `float`), so it's safe to provide a sequence of either type.

Answer (score 1):

This is the covariant vs contravariant problem.

Let X be a subtype of Y be a subtype of Z.

If I have a method that expects list[Y], and only ever reads that list, then it is perfectly safe to pass list[X]. The method expects to read an X, and it gets a Y instead, which is a subtype of X. Everything is okay. This is called a covariant argument.

If I have a method that expects list[Y], and only ever writes to that list, then it is perfectly safe to pass list[Z].  Values of type Y can fit well into list[Z].  This is called a contravariant argument.

If the method expects to both read and write to the list, then I have to pass an argument of precisely type list[Y].

Comment: You left out the relevant term: `list` is an *invariant* type, as when `x` is a subtype of `y`, `list[x]` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `list[y]`.